# Postgres tsrange, filter by date and time

Tags: postgresql

I have an `events` table that has a field called `duration` thats of type `tsrange` and that captures the beginning and end time of an event thats of type `timestamp`. What I want is to be able to filter all events across a certain date range and then filter those events by time. So for instance, a user should be able to filter for all events happening between (inclusive) `12-15-2019` to `12-17-2019` and that are playing at 9PM. To do this, the user submits a date range which filters all events in that date range:

```
WHERE lower(duration)::date <@ '[start, finish]'::daterange
```

In the above `start` and `finish` are user submitted parameters.

Then I want to filter those events by events that are playing during a specific time e.g. 9PM, essentially only show events that have 9PM between their start and end time.

So if I have the following table:

```
id    duration
---  ------------------------------------
 A    2019-12-21 19:00...2019-12-22 01:00
 B    2019-12-17 16:00...2019-12-17 18:00
 C    2019-12-23 19:00...2019-12-23 21:00
 D    2019-12-23 19:00...2019-12-24 01:00
 E    2019-12-27 14:00...2019-12-27 16:00
```

And the user submits a date range of `2019-12-21` to `2019-12-27` then event B will be filtered out. Then the user submits a time of 9:00PM (21:00), in which case A, C, and D will be returned.

**EDIT**

I was able to get it to work using the following:

```
WHERE duration @> (lower(duration)::date || ' 21:00:00')::timestamp
```

Where the 21:00 above is the user data, but it seems a bit hackish

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks I made the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tsrange` contains a timestamp at 9 p.m. if and only if 9 p.m. on the starting day or 9 p.m. on the following day are part of the range.

You can use that to write your condition.

An example:

```
lower(r)::date + TIME '21:00' <@ r OR
(lower(r)::date + 1) + TIME '21:00' <@ r
```

is a test if `r` contains some timestamp at 9 p.m.

Comment: That I get, but if a user submits 9:00, then I will need to compare that time with a date and time of a tsrange, which I am unsure of how to do. I can convert the tsrange to just time, but then if something start at 8:00PM and finishes at 2:00AM the next day I would be checking if 21:00 is in the range of 20:00...01:00, which can't be compared since the end is less than the start. I added more info to the question.

Comment: I have added an example to the answer, I hooe it is clear now.

Comment: Why is the OR needed? Wouldn't you just need `lower(r)::date + TIME '21:00' <@ r`?

Comment: If `r` is `[2019-12-20 23:00:00,2019-12-22 09:00:00]`, then `r` does not contain `2019-12-20 21:00:00`, but it contains `2019-12-21 21:00:00`.

Answer (score 2):

The user input `from 2019-12-21 to 2019-12-27 at 21:00` means that he is interested in

```
select generate_series(timestamp '2019-12-21 21:00', '2019-12-27 21:00', '1 day') as t

          t
---------------------
 2019-12-21 21:00:00
 2019-12-22 21:00:00
 2019-12-23 21:00:00
 2019-12-24 21:00:00
 2019-12-25 21:00:00
 2019-12-26 21:00:00
 2019-12-27 21:00:00
(7 rows)
```

Hence you should check whether the `duration` column contains one of the timestamp:

```
select distinct e.*
from events e
cross join generate_series(timestamp '2019-12-21 21:00', '2019-12-27 21:00', '1 day') as t
where duration @> t

 id |                   duration
----+-----------------------------------------------
 A  | ["2019-12-21 19:00:00","2019-12-22 01:10:00")
 C  | ["2019-12-23 19:00:00","2019-12-23 21:10:00")
 D  | ["2019-12-23 19:00:00","2019-12-24 01:10:00")
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, but Laurenz answered first and did solve my problem.